# Error using cv.CreateHist in Python OpenCV as well as strange absence of certain cv attributes

Tags: python, attributes, opencv, histogram

I am getting an error (see below) when trying to use `cv.CreateHist` in Python. I
am also noticing another alarming problem. If I spit out all of the attributes
of the `cv` module into a file, and then I search them, I find that a ton of
common things are missing.

For example, `cv.TermCriteria()` is not there; `cv.ConnectedComp` is not there; and
`cv.CvRect` is not there.

Everything about my installation, with Open CV 2.2, worked just fine. I can plot
images, make `CvScalars`, and call plenty of the functions, like cv.CamShift...
but there are a dozen or so of these hit-or-miss functions or data structures
that are simply missing with no explanation.

Here's my code for `cv.CreateHist`:

```
import cv
q = cv.CreateHist([1],1,cv.CV_HIST_ARRAY)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: x9y��
```

The weird wingding stuff is actually what it spits out at the command line, not a copy-paste error. Can anyone help figure this out? It's incredibly puzzling.

Ely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for CvRect, see [the documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/introduction.html). It says such types are represented as Pythonic tuples.

As for your call to CreateHist, you may be passing the arguments in wrong order. See [createhist in the docs for python opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/imgproc_histograms.html#createhist).